# Image not showing in Rails project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I put some images in a new rails project . But like in my previous html pages these images don't show up in rails application .

**view page code for image**

```
 <div class="item"><a href="<%= asset_path('01.jpg')%>" title="This is an image title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="<%= asset_path('1@2x.jpg')%>"><img src="<%= asset_path('01.jpg')%>" class="img-responsive" alt="img"></a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="<%= asset_path('02.jpg')%>" title="This is an image title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="<%= asset_path('2@2x.jpg')%>"><img src="<%= asset_path('02.jpg')%>" class="img-responsive " alt="img"></a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="<%= asset_path('03.jpg')%>" title="This is an image title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="<%= asset_path('3@2x.jpg')%>"><img src="<%= asset_path('03.jpg')%>" class="img-responsive " alt="img"></a></div>
```

Comment: your images are placed in app/assets/images folder...right?

Comment: yes.My image placed in app/assets/images folder

Comment: try to do `http://localhost:3000/01.jpg` in browser

Comment: you want image as link?

Comment: Not working.This part of code is my dashboard code.

Comment: have you tried to access image in browser?

Answer (score 1):

They are all images, right?

Why not use `image_path` or `image_url` like:

```
<div class="item"><a href="<%= image_path('01.jpg')%>" title="This is an image title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="<%= asset_path('1@2x.jpg')%>"><img src="<%= image_path('01.jpg')%>" class="img-responsive" alt="img"></a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="<%= image_path('02.jpg')%>" title="This is an image title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="<%= asset_path('2@2x.jpg')%>"><img src="<%= image_path('02.jpg')%>" class="img-responsive " alt="img"></a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="<%= image_path('03.jpg')%>" title="This is an image title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="<%= asset_path('3@2x.jpg')%>"><img src="<%= image_path('03.jpg')%>" class="img-responsive " alt="img"></a></div>
```

[Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

```
image_path("rails.png")
# => "/assets/rails.png"

image_url("rails.png")
# => "http://www.example.com/assets/rails.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this helper "<%= image_tag('imagename')%>" to get it done. Like,

```
<%= image_tag("image.jpg") %>
// output:
<img alt="Image" src="/assets/image.jpg" />

<%= image_tag("/logos/logo.png", width: '32', height: '32', alt: 'Site Logo', class: "logo") %>

// output: 
<img alt="Site Logo" src="/assets/logos/logo.png" width="32" height="32" class="logo" />
```

For more info about this image tag helper please visit [API DOC](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)

Comment: You have to put this helper tag in view file . Like any ERB template file . And This helper will get the images from the "assets/image" folder . Even you can provide extra class or stuff with this helper . This is helpful please visit Rails Guide . Or the Link I gave . And feel free to ask more question . And remember to upvote answers or check it as solutions please.

Comment: Its not working any more.My repo is only 6 so I can't upvote your answer.

Comment: are you saying , that image helper is not working ? what are facing tell me.